# Split a macro call and its argument in conditional

Tags: macros, conditionals

How can one split a macro call and its argument in a conditional? Why doesn't `\ifnum 1=1\textbf\else\textit\fi{Foo}` work? Why it yields error “Too many }'s”?

Comment: I don't exactly understand the question, but you need a couple of `\expandafter`s there, as in `\ifnum1=1\relax\expandafter\textbf\else\expandafter\textit\fi{Foo}`.

Comment: The argument of `\textbf` is `\else` and for `\textit` is `\fi`. Also add a space or `\relax` after `\ifnum1=1`, otherwise `\textbf` is already expanded, *before* the comparison in `\ifnum` is complete.

Comment: @campa Can you write an answer?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I was kind of waiting for some context, but maybe there's nothing more to say...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Heiko pointed out in his comment, `\textbf` is eating `\else` as argument, and `\textit` takes `\fi`. You thus need `\expandafter` in order to tell TeX to wait and finish the if-statement before expanding `\textbf` and `\textit`. You should then use

```
\ifnum1=1\relax\expandafter\textbf\else\expandafter\textit\fi{Foo}
```

or

```
\ifnum1=1 \expandafter\textbf\else\expandafter\textit\fi{Foo}
```

Notice either `\relax`or the space after the `\ifnum` statement, see e.g. Chapter 13.8 of TeX by Topic. (I'm pretty sure the issue has been already discussed somewhere here but I can't find it...)

Comment: Notwithstanding that comparing 1 to 1 is somehat pointless: `\csname text\ifnum1=1 bf\else it\fi\endcsname{Foo}` might do the trick without the need of using `\expandafter`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Cool. And obvious, when you think about it. (Maybe an `\expandafter` before `\csname` could be safer in some situations?) I agree that 1=1 is weird, but I guess the OP was just playing with this kind of constructs and reduced the problem to its root.

Comment: TeX will in any case expand expandable tokens when gathering the tokens for `\csname` until finding a matching `\endcsname`. Thus an `\expandafter`right before `\csname` to ensure expansion of the probably expandable token right behind `\csname` is not necessary. With `\def\bar{foo}` the sequence `\csname foo\endcsname` yields the same as `\csname\bar\endcsname`, i.e. the token `\foo`. You can also do `\expandafter\csname\bar\endcsname` if you like - expanding the first `\expandafter`yields: `\csname foo\endcsname`. The final result will be the same, the token `\foo`.

Comment: Thx. I thought I remembered a situation where I needed an `\expandafter` but it was probably something else.

Comment: Perhaps it was something like `\expandafter\let\csname foo\expandafter\endcsname\csname bar\endcsname` in order to obtain `\let\foo\bar` .